# How to copy choosen rows from table A to table B with conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, arraylist

I want have to create specific tab from my json response. I need:

```
markers: [
      position: {
         lat:50.8999208,
          lng:20.6258000
      },
      vin: vinfromresponse
    },
    {
      position: {
         lat:50.8911111,
          lng:20.6259999
      },
      vin: vinfromresponse
    },
]
```

My json response from rest api looks like this (in this example it's one row but but in normal case I have array with a lot of objects which i want to assign to my new array)

```
[{"id":1,"vin":58222,"register_number":"TK2332","cost":1.32,"latitude":20.6285908,"longitude":50.872941,"service":false,"reservation":false}]
```

But in array which I want to create field name has to be named lat, lng, because my markers in google api won't print points if those two fields will be named in another way. I don't know how to assign data to it from my json resopnse to make it proper. I'm not familiar with javascript and I need some help.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at .map [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Have fun :P

```js
let response =[{"id":1,"vin":58222,"register_number":"TK2332","cost":1.32,"latitude":20.6285908,"longitude":50.872941,"service":false,"reservation":false}]


let obj ={}
obj.markers = response.map(res=>{
     return { 
       position: {
         lat:res.latitude,
         lng: res.longitude
      },
      vin: res.vin}
  }
)
console.log(obj)
```